# Flex throws "input in flex scanner failed" after parsing whole file?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I am trying to make a parser in C++ using Flex and Bison. I have seen "input in flex scanner failed" online only in posts which provide a bad file for parsing. But I am getting this error after my whole file is parsed correctly. Is there some bug where flex can't detect EOF properly? These are the relevant definitions:

Bison -

```
%union {
    char node;
    char gate;
    int index;
}

%token END;
%token <node> NODE;
%token <gate> GATE;
%token <index> INDEX;

%%

atpg:
    body END { cout << "Reading last line." << endl; };
body:
    assignments;
assignments:
    assignments assignment { cout << "Token: assignments - rec." << endl; }
    | assignment         { cout << "Token: assignments - first." << endl; };
assignment:
    outnode gatedec '(' nodelist ')'  {
        cout << "Token: assignment" << endl;
        g_gatelist[last_gate].setOutput(&g_nodelist[out_node]);
        for(int i : t_nodelist)
            g_gatelist[last_gate].addInput(&g_nodelist[i]);
        t_nodelist.clear();
        };
outnode:
    nodedec '='  {
        cout << "Token: outnode" << endl;
        out_node = last_node;
        };
nodedec:
    NODE INDEX  {
        num_nodes ++;
        if ($1 == 'i') input_nodes ++;
        if ($1 == 'o') output_nodes ++;

        new(&g_nodelist[$2]) Node($1, $2);
        last_node = $2;

        cout << g_nodelist[$2] << endl;
        };
gatedec:
    GATE INDEX  {
        num_gates ++;

        createGateFromName(&g_gatelist[$2], $1, $2);
        last_gate = $2;

        cout << "Gate: " << $1 << "-" << $2 << endl; 
        };
nodelist:
    nodedec nodelist { 
        cout << "Token: nodelist - rec" << endl;
        t_nodelist.push_back(last_node);
        }
    | nodedec {
        cout << "Token: nodelist - first" << endl;
        t_nodelist.push_back(last_node);
        };
```

Flex -

```
%{
#include "gatelist.tab.h"
#define YY_DECL extern "C" int yylex()
%}

INDEX    [0-9]+
GATE     and|or|not
NODE     n|i|o

%%

{GATE}      { yylval.gate = yytext[0]; return GATE; }

{NODE}      { yylval.node = yytext[0]; return NODE; }

{INDEX}     { yylval.index = atoi(yytext); return INDEX; }

[\(\)=]     { return yytext[0]; }

end         { return END; }

.|\n ;/* ignore */
%%
;
```

Input -

```
n3 = and1 ( i0 i1 i2 )
n4 = or2 ( i1 i2 )
n5 = not3 ( n4 )
n6 = and4 ( n5 n4 )
end
```

Output -

```
Node(n-3 = 0)
Token: outnode
Gate: a-1
Node(i-0 = 0)
Node(i-1 = 0)
Node(i-2 = 0)
Token: nodelist - first
Token: nodelist - rec
Token: nodelist - rec
Token: assignment
Token: assignments - first.
Node(n-4 = 0)
Token: outnode
Gate: o-2
Node(i-1 = 0)
Node(i-2 = 0)
Token: nodelist - first
Token: nodelist - rec
Token: assignment
Token: assignments - rec.
Node(n-5 = 0)
Token: outnode
Gate: n-3
Node(n-4 = 0)
Token: nodelist - first
Token: assignment
Token: assignments - rec.
Node(n-6 = 0)
Token: outnode
Gate: a-4
Node(n-5 = 0)
Node(n-4 = 0)
Token: nodelist - first
Token: nodelist - rec
Token: assignment
Token: assignments - rec.
Reading last line.
input in flex scanner failed
```

Comment: I did the best I could, but please read about how to prepare a [mcve]. It is impossible to test your code because (1) the actions depend on external functions and (2) the driver and Makefile or build procedure are not included. DO NOT just add definitions of the functions needed, since that would make a non-minimal example even longer. Instead, prepare a version without (unnecessary) actions (In your case, all actions are unnecessary) and include all other definitions used (yywrap and yyerror, for example, although I always prefer `%option noyywrap` in the flex file to avoid the need.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bison always augments the provided grammar by adding a goal rule which matches your provided start rule followed by an end-of-file indicator (token number 0), so that the input is forced to match a complete file. If you want to use your own end marker and terminate the parse when it has been recognised, you should use the `YYACCEPT` action in the associated action to cause the parse to terminate successfully without reading more tokens.

The error you are getting occurs when a flex scanner receives a read error when it attempts to read data. End of file is *not* an error, and I/O errors are fairly uncommon. Normally, this error indicates that an attempt was made to continue reading input after an end of file had been reported and `yyin` closed (or set to an invalid value). In general, you should avoid reading tokens after an end-of-file has been reported; although it often works, it is not fully supported and with certain scanner options it will produce unexpected results.

---

As a side issue, you will usually find that it is easier to use bison's built-in [trace facility](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Tracing) than to scatter printf's throughout your code. You will end up adding and removing the printf's, which is a nuisance, and they will never give you as complete a picture of what is going on as a bison trace.

Comment: I added YYACCEPT and it fixed the problem. I can't get the trace to work though, added both `YYDEBUG` and `--debug` flag

Comment: @udiboy1209: you only need `--debug` OR `#define YYDEBUG` but you also need `yydebug = 1;`. A common idiom is to put `#if YYDEBUG` `yydebug = 1;` `#endif` into `main` (if the parser includes are visible in main).

Comment: Probably this paragraph should be closer to the top of the documentation page. "Once you have compiled the program with trace facilities, the way to request a trace is to store a nonzero value in the variable yydebug. " People often seem to miss it. The assumption that programmers will actually read an entire page of documentation seems to be a thing of the past, if it were ever the case.